# Meaning of terms after analysis in Locust Load Testing

Tags: python, testing, load-testing, locust

I am using **Locust (Modern Open Source Load Testing Tool)** for Load testing of APIs.
As it is `simulation + analysis` tool, I am not able to understand some of the terms.
Below is the screen-shot of the test which I have done on the API.

[image: Test Run]

Terms I want to know about:

1. The relationship between `Number of users to simulate Vs Hatch Rate (Users Spawned/Second)`.
2. From the above image, the meaning of `Median (ms), Average (ms), Content Size(bytes)`.
3. `min_wait, max_wait`, the name of the variables which we override with own values in the `WebsiteUser(HttpLocust)` class, the significance of min_wait, max_wait.

Next, in the `Charts` tab, Locust shows 3 graphs, namely `(Total Requests/Second, Response Time (ms), Number of Users)`.
Not able to make sense of this charts,
In `Total Requests/Second`, should I look at peaks with respect to time as it is `Number of Users Vs Time Graphs`?
How do I make sense of all the charts?

Thank You.
Its a broad question, but I need to know about this terms, as for better understanding of the graphs, data which I get after doing the analysis.

Comment: These items should be defined in the relevant manuals. What did you find when you studied them and what did you not understand?

Answer (score 4):

> The relationship between Number of users to simulate Vs Hatch Rate
>   (Users Spawned/Second).

You define a number of user (locust) you want to spawn, at a given rate. **This gives you control of how fast users flood in**. For exemple, 100 user at 5 user/sec, it will take 100/5=20 second to reach 100 user.

> From the above image, the meaning of Median (ms), Average (ms),
>   Content Size(bytes).

Median, average response time of a given api endpoint, **over the entire testing time**. Content size is the size of the returned data from the endpoint.

> min_wait, max_wait, the name of the variables which we override with
>   own values in the WebsiteUser(HttpLocust) class, the significance of
>   min_wait, max_wait.

Please refer to the [doc](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/quickstart.html).

> Next, in the Charts tab, Locust shows 3 graphs, namely (Total
>   Requests/Second, Response Time (ms), Number of Users). Not able to
>   make sense of this charts, In Total Requests/Second, should I look at
>   peaks with respect to time as it is Number of Users Vs Time Graphs?

They are numbers of total RPS, response time and number of users, **counting all endpoints**, displayed in **realtime**. Peak response time is of special interest as you should investigate what happened at that time point (too many new users? a burst RPS?)